# How to Observe a JavaScript Button in a Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am looking for help please to observe when a button in the navbar of a Shiny App with `navbarPage` is clicked.

I have included a button right in the Shiny navbar with some javascript. I have provided an id to the button tag (‘id = btn_show’) and have introduced an observeevent to listen for ‘input$btn_show’. The button isn’t being observed though… what is required please? Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = 'Button Up',
  tabPanel('Tab 1'),
  tabPanel('Tab 1')
  , tags$script(HTML(
    "var header = $('.navbar> .container-fluid');
                   header.append('<div style=\"float:right; style=\"valign:middle;\"><button id = \"btn_show\">Show Controls</button></div>');
                    console.log(header)"))
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_show,{
    
    print('The button was observed')
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `onclick` attribute to your button:

```
<button id=\"btn_show\" onclick=\"Shiny.setInputValue(\\\"btn_show\\\", true, {priority: \\\"event\\\"})\">Show Controls</button>
```

I'm not sure the triple backslashes will work. If not, define a function:

```
function f(){
  Shiny.setInputValue(\"btn_show\", true, {priority: \"event\"})
}
```

Then `onclick = \"f()\"`.

## EDIT

Works like this:

```
  tags$script(HTML(
    "var header = $('.navbar> .container-fluid');
    var f = function(){Shiny.setInputValue(\"btn_show\", true, {priority: \"event\"})};
    header.append('<div style=\"float:right; valign:middle;\"><button id=\"btn_show\" onclick=\"f()\">Show Controls</button></div>');
    console.log(header)"))
```

Comment: Thnx for quick reply; I updated the code chuck to the following but still can’t see the observeevent printing out. "var header = $('.navbar> .container-fluid'); header.append('<div style=\"float:right; style=\"valign:middle;\"><button id=\"btn_show\" onclick=\"Shiny.setInputValue(\\\"btn_show\\\", true, {priority: \\\"event\\\"})\">Show Controls</button></div>'); console.log(header)"

Comment: Absolutely super thanks! The EDIT did the trick.